# Merging two layers

Tags: keras

How to replace the merge statement in newer version of keras. Newer version of keras doen't support the Merge.

```
for fsz in filter_sizes:
    l_conv = Conv1D(nb_filter=128,filter_length=fsz,activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
    l_pool = MaxPooling1D(5)(l_conv)
    convs.append(l_pool)

l_merge = Merge(mode='concat', concat_axis=1)(convs)
```

Answer (score 3):

This changed a while ago. Now you can use the `concatenate` layer. Documentation says:

> `keras.layers.concatenate()`
>
> Definition: concatenate(inputs, axis=-1, **kwargs)
>
> Type: Function of keras.layers.merge module
>
> *Functional interface to the Concatenate layer.*
>
> Arguments→ **inputs**: A list of input tensors (at least 2). **axis**: Concatenation axis. ****kwargs**: Standard layer keyword arguments.
>
> Returns→ A tensor, the concatenation of the inputs alongside axis *axis*.

Since you are using the Functional API:

```
from keras.layers import concatenate
l_merge = concatenate(convs, axis=1)
```